# Bifold door "flat-lying" hinges?

Tags: doors, hinges

Painted my old bifold doors and want to replace the 2.5" tall brass hinges that span across the back of two doors, like this:

[image]

Problem is, the old hinges lie perfectly flat against the doors so they're great.  But the new hinges I got from HD and all the ones I can find have a hump where the pin is.  Here's a photo of them:

[image]

I'm assuming the hump would dig into the doors if I screwed them in, since there isn't a gap between the doors.  I'm trying to find hinges like the old ones that lie flat, but in a brushed silver/nickel color.  Also decent quality ones, the HD ones have a decent amount of wiggle and play unlike the old ones.  Any suggestions, brands, product links, or even just what you would call hinges that lie flat would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your new hinge will create a very slight gap between the two doors.

Unless your door tolerance is *incredibly* tight, this will not create any issues whatsoever. You will end up with maybe a 1/8" gap between the two hinged doors, but this will be compensated for by that same ~1/8" reduction in the gap at the open side of the door. It's unlikely that you'll notice the difference after a week.

Looking at all my bi-fold doors, there is a very small gap between the doors anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Most home stores will carry the cheaper made hinges. Try a cabinet making store. All you need to do it carve or file a small depression in the doors where the hinge will seat to handle that hump. If it's particle doors, hitting the hinge with a mallet while it's in place will make the groove for the hump.